# How to apply javascript on SelectedIndexChanging of grid view

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have wriiten a javascript which I am using it **onblur** event of textbox which is inside a gridview. The same script should fire for me when I perform **SelectedIndexChanging** of gridview. This is my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function total(txtQuantity, txtRate, txtAmount) {
    var col1;
    var totalcol1 = 0;
    var weight = document.getElementById(txtQuantity).value;
    var rate = document.getElementById(txtRate).value;
    var tot = weight * rate;
    document.getElementById(txtAmount).value = tot.toFixed(2).toString();
    var grid = document.getElementById('<%=grdInvoice.ClientID %>');


    for (i = 0; i < grid.rows.length; i++) {
        col1 = grid.rows[i].cells[4];
        //col2 = grid.rows[i].cells[1];

        for (j = 0; j < col1.childNodes.length; j++) {
            if (col1.childNodes[j].type == "text") {
                if (!isNaN(col1.childNodes[j].value) && col1.childNodes[j].value != "") {
                    totalcol1 += parseInt(col1.childNodes[j].value)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('<%= lblTotal.ClientID %>').innerHTML = totalcol1.toFixed(2).toString();
    document.getElementById('<%=lblResultbalance.ClientID%>').innerHTML = totalcol1.toFixed(2).toString();
    document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>').value = totalcol1.toFixed(2).toString();
}
```

Can some one help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your event

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "script", "total('" + txt1.ClientID + "','" + txt2.ClientID + "','" + txt3.ClientID + "')", true);
```